# How to use NumberFormat method inside a loop in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in VBA and I have a range and when the value in the range is small than 0, then I'll multiply the value by 1000 and then change its format by using the `NumberFormat` method. But somehow it doesn't work. The error code is on this line: `RngToThousand.NumberFormat = "$-#,##0,""K"""`. The error says "Object required", I guess there is something wrong with the datatype. Anyhelp would be appreciated, thanks.

Below is the code I have:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RngToNum As Range
Set RngToNum = Range("H2:J21")
For Each Rng In RngToNum
    If Rng.Value < 0 Then
        RngToThousand = Rng.Value * 1000
        RngToThousand.NumberFormat = "$-#,##0,""K"""
    Else: Rng.NumberFormat = ""
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Where do you declare RngToThousand? It should be a range object. Is it?

Comment: And why are you multiplying by 1000?  If the original number was -4000, you are going to end up showing `$-4,000K` which is 1000 times too big (assuming you are using the `K` to signify thousands).

Comment: There's not enough context for this question to be answerable IMO. The variables just pop out of nowhere, that's not a [mcve]... it hardly compiles. Make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module: if your code still compiles, then you need to [edit] your post so we can see where `RngToThousand` comes from.

Comment: You can do it all for the entire range in 1 line `RngToNum.NumberFormat = "[<0]""$""#,""$-""#,##0,""K"";"another format for else"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumberFormat requires an object such as Range and your RngToThousand variable is not an object. I tested the following and it worked ok:

```
    If Rng.Value < 0 Then
        Rng.Value = Rng.Value * 1000
        Rng.NumberFormat = "$-#,##0,""K"""
    ...
```

Comment: You probably mean `Rng.Value > 0` - greater than zero.

Comment: It works! If I want to assign a new object to Rng.Value * 1000 instead Using Rng.Value, how to make it?

Comment: @JonX you may create new object by using: 
`Set rngNew = Range("K2")` then assign value to it:
`rngNew.Value = rng.Value * 1000`